# Function argument with mutables, avoid `if arg is None` construct

Tags: python-3.x, default, dry, mutable

Is there a way to avoid repetitive code like the following? Imaging 20 other functions taking mutable parameters with default values.
Everytime checking the argument for `None`, everytime assigning default value in `if` branch.
Putting the default in the function signature does not work as python caches the value the first time the function is called.

```
import datetime as dt

def dt_to_str(dtime: dt.datetime = None):
    if dtime is None:
        dtime = dt.datetime.now()

    return dtime.strftime("%c")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(dt_to_str())
```

Comment: You could write a decorator, but that might not be worth the effort. Can you provide more details about your actual use-case?

Comment: Do all of your functions follow the same pattern: a single function call inside the `if` block, and a single function call in the return?

Comment: I have several cases where i could refactor two functions into one using a default argument. One function takes no parameter, the other function take one parameter, but does the same thing. Therefore they could be one function if they had a default argument. It's quite tedious to provide the `None` workaround for all of them. I would merely like to have a more general solution where i could provide the function with mutable defaults without writing two additional lines of repetitive code for each of them. Maybe it isn't such a bad idea of providing a decorator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in most cases, the `if arg is None: arg = ...` syntax is the best solution. But if you are really bothered by it, here's a decorator which works for single-argument functions:

```py
from functools import wraps

def default_argument(arg_factory):
    def decorator(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def wrapped(arg=None):
            if arg is None:
                arg = arg_factory()
            return f(arg)
        return wrapped
    return decorator
```

Usage examples below: you can either pass a reference to an existing function, or a `lambda`.

```py
import datetime as dt

@default_argument(dt.datetime.now)
def dt_to_str(dtime):
    return dtime.strftime('%c')

print(dt_to_str())
# Mon Oct 25 00:16:03 2021

@default_argument(lambda: [])
def thing_with_list(lst):
    return lst + [123]

print(thing_with_list())
# [123]
```